# Convert (manually) from uint32_t to 4 chars

Tags: c++, debugging, typedef

I have a program with a special typedef, used in many place to assign unique code to components in the software.

```
typedef uint32_t FourCharCode;
```

At a point, I have a function that use such a code to do its job. I need to debug in this function

```
extern "C" ___DllExport void A_function(FourCharCode in_type)
{
    FourCharCode x = 'KjfG';
    FourCharCode y = 'tdkf';
    FourCharCode z = '5vpO';

    switch (in_type) {
        case x:
            // Do something
            break;
        case y:
            // Do something
            break;
        case z:
            // Do something
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return XX::NoError;
}
```

Obviously, when I put a breakpoint to see what is the value of `in_type`, I obtain an unsigned int ('1918980169').

My question:

Is there a way, in MSVC 2013 debugger, to display the uint32_t value as something readable?

Or

What could I do manually (using a calculator, a python script or anything else useful) to retrieve the 4 chars hidden behind this uint (I am not against using a paper and a pen, but I don't see how I can do the computation)?

Comment: Try typing this into a watch window: `(char*)(&in_type),4`.

Comment: @Beta-Carotin You made my day, that's perfectly fits my needs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the values manually, displaying the value in hexadecimal is much easier than decimal. `'5vpO'` is 896954447 in decimal, but if you right-click in the Watch window, you can choose Hexadecimal Display and it shows up as 0x3576704f. 0x35 is `'5'`, 0x76 is `'v'`, 0x70 is `'p'`, and 0x4f is `'O'`. Or to display as hexadecimal on a per-variable basis, append `,h` to the variable name in your watch window, as in `z,h`.

Alternatively, you can cast the variable as a `char*` and display it as an array of length 4. If you add `(char*)&z,4` to your Watch window, it displays `"Opv5"`. This is the reverse of the string as declared on x86 PCs, because they are little-endian, but is easy enough to read.

As MuertoExcobito [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564572/4896941), you can [Natvis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ620914%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to create a custom view of any type.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use an union. like that :

```
struct fourCharCode
{
    char fourCode[4];
};

union UFourCode
{
    fourCharCode fourChar;
    __int32_t myInt32;
};
```

And you use it like

```
int main() 
{

    UFourCode u;
    u.int32 = 1918980169; //From your question

    std::cout << u.fourChar.fourCode; 
}
```

The output is :

`IPar`

Comment: Don't write `typedef struct {...} X;`. Write `struct X {...};`. This is C++, not C.

Comment: The structure of my program doesn't allows me to use this tip, and I can't print on the standard output, so I can't really use your solution. But +1 for the union declaration I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`.natvis`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) file, which specifies the display format for a  native C/C++ type in the VS debugger (eg. watch window), if you wanted to display it as something other than with the default viewer. The natvis is placed in your `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Visualizers` directory, and will be loaded automatically on the next invocation of the debugger (no restart of VS required).

You can get elaborate with your natvis files, including turning them into a full plugin with installer (aka. [VSIX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx)), however, just placing it in that directory manually is easiest, if you're not planning on wide distribution.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, without success:`<Type Name="unsigned int"><DisplayString>{this} 4Chars=( (char*)&this,4 )</DisplayString></Type>` Are you sure it is possible to customize rendering of a primitive type? All examples I found on the Internet are related to classes

Comment: I wouldn't try to change the visualization of `unsigned int` (or other built-in-type), even if it is possible, it might cause undesired effects. It would be better to define FourCharCode as a real class/struct, and create a visualizer for it instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't redefine FourCharCode: it comes from a host program I have to plug into as a Dll :/